# Asp.Net caching specific querystring parameters, not others

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

I can't figure out how to cache this page under the different URL formats posted below.

I would like to cache these pages:

```
/folder/
/folder/?page=2
/folder/?id=17
/folder/?id=17&page=2
```

I don't want pages that have the querystring param "search" to be cached at all.

```
/folder/?search=1&param1=1&param2=2
```

I have looked some at the VaryByCustom parameter of OutputCache, but I have no clue how to stop the bottom URL from being cached.

**EDIT** - Sample page

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="cache.aspx.vb" Inherits="cache" %>
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="page;id" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

    <%=date.now %>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You would have to specify ONLY the querystring parameters you want to be cached. Try using the VaryByParam property and setting it to a semicolon-separated list of strings; in your case, try the following.

VaryByParam = "page,param1,param2"

Comment: VaryByParam="page;id" works correctly for all of the pages, however /folder/?search=1&param1=1 is cached and referencing the output from the /folder/ page request.

Comment: You have to be more specific. /folder/ is not a page, it's a folder.

Comment: By default, it requests /folder/Default.aspx to be more specific. Are you putting this directive on the the page or in some control? Can you  paste what you have?

Comment: I added a sample page, there is nothing to it, just a OutputCache declarative and a timestamp.  If you replicate the page, you will notice the search querystrings are cached as well.

Comment: You can't "cache a page" but then have it serve non-cached versions if the search querystring parameter is repeated. There is no logic for this AFAIK. My suggestion is to encapsulate different parts of your page into .ascx controls and apply ouput caching logic to each of them.

Comment: That was the whole point of my question, not sure what took so long for you to realize that.

Comment: I'm sorry for trying to help you whilst misinterpreting your logic and then providing an alternative solution.